# Dynamic import of modules giving "SCRIPT1002: Syntax error" in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am dynamically loading a module (sortable-js) using the import() function syntax. This works perfectly in chrome but gives a syntax error in edge.

I assume this is not supported, but is there another way to achieve the same result (i.e. dynamically load the module later in the page life cycle rather than statically when it loads)

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
<script>
  import("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.10.1/Sortable.min.js")
    .then(module => {
        var list = document.getElementById('items');
        Sortable.create(list);
    });
</script>
```

You can play with it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/qje0zsLr/

(Hit F12 in Edge and you can see the error on the console)

Comment: Do you need a polyfill?